# HTTPWebRequest to see if Website is availible / Credentials fail

Tags: c#, wpf, proxy, httpwebrequest

I am in a company domain network. We got network restrictions.
We **can't ping** IPs outside our network.

I have to **check if a Internet connection** is up by making a HTTPWebRequest on google.com.

We use a proxy for our internet connection and use a **proxy.pac**.
The Programm should still work if i am not in the company and i am directly connectet to the internet.

Check if i am in the Company --> use Proxy. If connectet direktly --> use without proxy.

I tryed this but i still got (Error 407 Authentification required) if i am at the company network but it works if i am connectet direktly.

```
try
        {
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(_URL);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.Uri);
            request.Timeout = 1000;
            //request.Accept = "*/*";
            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("1**.208.***.***:8080");
            //request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.Proxy = proxy;
            request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //request.UserAgent = "Foo";
            //request.Accept = "*/*";
            //request.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            _PingByURL = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK; //_PingByURL is bool.
        }
        catch 
        {

            _PingByURL =false;
        }
```

My App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>      
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>       
  </startup>
  <system.net>
      <defaultProxy enabled ="true" useDefaultCredentials = "true">
          <proxy usesystemdefault ="True" bypassonlocal="True"/>
      </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

So i need the Right Credentials. How can i use the domain credentials from the domain i logged on?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The PAC url is not your proxy. The PAC file contains information regarding the proxy IP and port. That is what you need to pass to the HttpWebRequest object.

Also Instead of System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials pass your domain credentials.

Comment: but how i get the proxy out of the pac? or can i use my default proxy? It should be the proxy out of the pac.

Comment: even if i use the ip from the proxy it doesn't work.